# Игра на pygame не собирается в .EXE

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Есть простенькая змейка на pygame с 2-мя картинками и фоновой музыкой. Пробовал собрать через pyinstaller, файлы добавляются, но сам pygame не скачивается, даже если прописываешь hidden imports согласно этой (https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/143934/) и этой (https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/143934/) инструкции. И даже если меняешь `.spec`-файл

Терминал выдает `no module pygame`

Пока все найденные ответы на stackoverflow не решили проблему. Может кто сталкивался именно с установкой `pygame` при сборке?

Ниже скрины структуры игры и логов:

**Структура**
[image: структура]

**Логги**

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\1>pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "images/lose.jpeg;images" --

add-data "images/win.jpg;images" --hidden-import='pygame' labirint.py345 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.3.0
346 INFO: Python: 3.12.1374 INFO: Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22621-SP0
376 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\Desktop\1\labirint.spec384 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\1']697 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
697 INFO: checking Analysis697 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
698 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...700 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
713 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...2211 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2291 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...3929 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5162 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...5261 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5261 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...5266 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.dll
5266 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Desktop\1\labirint.py5271 INFO: Analyzing hidden import "'pygame'"
5272 ERROR: Hidden import "'pygame'" not found5272 INFO: Processing module hooks...
5280 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (4 entries)5292 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
5298 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...5300 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
5304 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries5435 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): []
5435 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): []5530 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll', dependency of 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.dll'.
...
...
5649 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent5649 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\1\build\labirint\PYZ-00.pyz
5896 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\Desktop\1\build\labirint\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.5916 INFO: checking PKG
5916 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent5917 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) labirint.pkg
8032 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) labirint.pkg completed successfully.8039 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
8039 INFO: checking EXE8040 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
8041 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc8041 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\User\Desktop\1\dist\labirint.exe
8145 INFO: Copying icon to EXE8231 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
8231 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE8317 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
8547 INFO: Fixing EXE headers9551 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

**Результат запуска `labirint.exe`**
[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

Итак, решения нашел, возможно кому-то будет полезно.

Проблема решилась установкой `auto-py-to-exe`

Установка:
`pip install auto-py-to-exe`

Запуск
В том же терминале набрать:
`auto-py-to-exe`
Откроется интерфейс. Осталось только настроить!

[image: первый скрин]

В **Script Location** добавляем путь до нашего исполняемого файла с игрой.
Выбираем вариант **One File** и прячем консоль, выбрав **Window Based (hide the console)**

Идём в **Additional Files** и жмем **Add Folder**, т.к. все медиа-файлы хранятся в одной папке возле исполняемого файла.

Переходим в **Advanced**

[image: second screen]

Здесь добавляем **pygame** только в **--hidden-import** и **-collect-submodules**

Далее жмем синию кнопку **CONVERT .PY TO .EXE**

Уаля, всё готово. Идем забирать всего один файл без всего лишнего.

Также сборщик сгенерировал строку для **pyinstaller**. Можно, как вариант еще попробоваать воспользоваться им:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "<ПОЛНЫЙ-ПУТЬ-ДО-ПАПКИ-С-МЕДИА>/images:images/" --hidden-import "pygame" --collect-submodules "pygame"  "<ПОЛНЫЙ-ПУТЬ-ДО-ИГРА.РУ>/labirint.py"
```

- Вместо `<ПОЛНЫЙ-ПУТЬ-ДО-ПАПКИ-С-МЕДИА>` нужно указать свой путь до папки, где у вас находятся картинки и/или музыка.
- Вместо `<ПОЛНЫЙ-ПУТЬ-ДО-ИГРА.РУ>` нужно указать путь до исполняемого файла с исходным кодом.

Можно без попробовать указания абсолютных путей:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "images:images/" --hidden-import "pygame" --collect-submodules "pygame"  "labirint.py"
```