# Сборка Python-проекта pyinstaller-ом. После старта exe-файла выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии модуля

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Собираю проект из нескольких питон-скриптов. IKS_pro.py - стартовый скрипт, с него весь проект "начинается". Используется tkinter в качестве GUI. Так же подгружаются некоторые дополнительные модули (tkcalendar). Pyinstaller нормально собирает exe-файл; командная строка:

```
pyinstaller  --clean -n "IKS pro" -d imports -w -i "IKS_pro.ico" IKS_pro.py
```

После старта exe-файла выдаётся сообщение об ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IKS_pro.py", line 516, in <module>
  File "IKS_pro.py", line 66, in __init__
  File "IKS_pro.py", line 200, in init_menu
  File "tkcalendar\dateentry.py", line 128, in __init__
  File "tkcalendar\calendar_.py", line 259, in __init__
  File "babel\dates.py", line 285, in get_day_names
  File "babel\core.py", line 773, in days
  File "babel\core.py", line 439, in _data
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 137, in load
  File "babel\localedata.py", line 143, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'
```

файлик numbers.py в соответствующей папке site-packages\babel присутствует.
Поскольку первый раз "собираю" exe-файл то просто не знаю за что зацепиться.
Прошу помочь советом.

Comment: Попробуйте через auto-py-to-exe собрать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559630/Игра-на-pygame-не-собирается-в-exe

Comment: Amgarak, спасибо. Попробовал с помощью auto-py-to-exe... Но это лишь надстройка над pyinstaller-ом. И ошибка, к сожалению, повторилась (((

Comment: А без сборки в exe-файл всё работает?

Comment: Да, без сборки всё работает. Но с проблемой разобрался. В том числе с помощью твоей, Amgarak, подсказки. В диалоговом окне auto-py-to-exe "собрал" командную строку для pyinstaller-a. Далее copy-paste-перенёс эту строку в стандартный bat-файл и сборка произошла без ошибок последующего старта. Спасибо тебе!